# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on adding uiimageview to custom uibutton on iPad 5.0 simulator but works on iPad 6.0 simulator

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

My .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NavigationBarButton : UIButton

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *barButtonImage;

@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *barButtonLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withImage:(UIImage *) image withTitle:(NSString *) title;
```

My .m file

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withImage:(UIImage *) image withTitle:(NSString *) title


{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self) 

{  
        self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        self.frame = frame;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        barButtonImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 1, 18, 23)]autorelease];
        [barButtonImage setImage:image];

        barButtonLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 26, 50, 10)]autorelease];
        barButtonLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        barButtonLabel.text = title;
        barButtonLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
        barButtonLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        [self addSubview:barButtonLabel];
        [self addSubview:barButtonImage];

        //[barButtonImage release];
        //[barButtonLabel release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

but the app crashes on [self addSubview:barButtonLabel] which is strange because the code runs well on iPad 6.0 simulator but not on iPad 5.0 or iPad 5.1 simulator

Answer (score 0):

once check with this one

add this on in .m file

```
@synthesize barButtonImage, barButtonLabel;
```

Comment: yeah its working now but I think the issue was something else because of which it was throwing error ... thanks for the reply